# Store json data in a local variable

Tags: php, json, gdata

I get `gdata` of `youtube video` from the `URL`. It returns the `json code` like this.

```
{"apiVersion":"2.1","data":{"id":"4TSJhIZmL0A","uploaded":"2008-07-15T18:11:59.000Z","updated":"2013-05-01T21:01:49.000Z","uploader":"burloandbardsey","category":"News","title":"bbc news start up theme","description":"bbc","thumbnail":{"sqDefault":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/4TSJhIZmL0A/default.jpg","hqDefault":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/4TSJhIZmL0A/hqdefault.jpg"},"player":{"default":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4TSJhIZmL0A&feature=youtube_gdata_player","mobile":"http://m.youtube.com/details?v=4TSJhIZmL0A"},"content":{"5":"http://www.youtube.com/v/4TSJhIZmL0A?version=3&f=videos&app=youtube_gdata","1":"rtsp://v5.cache7.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQlAL2aGhIk04RMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp","6":"rtsp://v5.cache7.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQlAL2aGhIk04RMYESARFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp"},"duration":15,"aspectRatio":"widescreen","rating":4.6683936,"likeCount":"354","ratingCount":386,"viewCount":341066,"favoriteCount":0,"commentCount":155,"accessControl":{"comment":"allowed","commentVote":"allowed","videoRespond":"allowed","rate":"allowed","embed":"allowed","list":"allowed","autoPlay":"allowed","syndicate":"allowed"}}}
```

But I working `internet connection` only on my `remote server` not a `local system`.

Now my question is,

For my testing purpose, Before using `json_decode()`, I want to store the above `json code` in a local variable.
but it gives `syntax error`.

for example,

```
$myJson = {"apiVersion":"2.1","data":{"id":"4TSJhIZmL0A","uploaded":"2008-07-15T18:11:59.000Z","updated":"2013-05-01T21:01:49.000Z","uploader":"burloandbardsey","category":"News","title":"bbc news start up theme","description":"bbc","thumbnail":{"sqDefault":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/4TSJhIZmL0A/default.jpg","hqDefault":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/4TSJhIZmL0A/hqdefault.jpg"},"player":{"default":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4TSJhIZmL0A&feature=youtube_gdata_player","mobile":"http://m.youtube.com/details?v=4TSJhIZmL0A"},"content":{"5":"http://www.youtube.com/v/4TSJhIZmL0A?version=3&f=videos&app=youtube_gdata","1":"rtsp://v5.cache7.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQlAL2aGhIk04RMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp","6":"rtsp://v5.cache7.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQlAL2aGhIk04RMYESARFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp"},"duration":15,"aspectRatio":"widescreen","rating":4.6683936,"likeCount":"354","ratingCount":386,"viewCount":341066,"favoriteCount":0,"commentCount":155,"accessControl":{"comment":"allowed","commentVote":"allowed","videoRespond":"allowed","rate":"allowed","embed":"allowed","list":"allowed","autoPlay":"allowed","syndicate":"allowed"}}};
```

how I store my `json data` in local variable

Comment: Store the JSON as a string

Answer (score 4):

store it inside `''` like string, like this

```
$myJson = '{"apiVersion":"2.1","data":{"id":"4TSJhIZmL0A","uploaded":"2008-07-15T18:11:59.000Z","updated":"2013-05-01T21:01:49.000Z","uploader":"burloandbardsey","category":"News","title":"bbc news start up theme","description":"bbc","thumbnail":{"sqDefault":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/4TSJhIZmL0A/default.jpg","hqDefault":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/4TSJhIZmL0A/hqdefault.jpg"},"player":{"default":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4TSJhIZmL0A&feature=youtube_gdata_player","mobile":"http://m.youtube.com/details?v=4TSJhIZmL0A"},"content":{"5":"http://www.youtube.com/v/4TSJhIZmL0A?version=3&f=videos&app=youtube_gdata","1":"rtsp://v5.cache7.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQlAL2aGhIk04RMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp","6":"rtsp://v5.cache7.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQlAL2aGhIk04RMYESARFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp"},"duration":15,"aspectRatio":"widescreen","rating":4.6683936,"likeCount":"354","ratingCount":386,"viewCount":341066,"favoriteCount":0,"commentCount":155,"accessControl":{"comment":"allowed","commentVote":"allowed","videoRespond":"allowed","rate":"allowed","embed":"allowed","list":"allowed","autoPlay":"allowed","syndicate":"allowed"}}}';
```

Comment: If my json contains with `' .. '` means it will ended one. what i have to do?

Comment: How do i escape, If i am going this way `mysqli_real_escape_string({"apiVersion":......")`; It also be an error.

Comment: I use php [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) functionality to store my json data. It will be fine for the any of `syntax error`. But after i done `json_decode($data);` it displays nothing.

Comment: @Ranjith Do 1 thing. First decode the JSON using `JSON_DECODE` and again encode it using `JSON_ENCODE` with available JSON constants http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php

Comment: my json contains '' ( single quote ) in its content too. so there the string breaks and it gives error.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myJson = '{"apiVersion":"2.1","data":{"id":"4TSJhIZmL0A","uploaded":"2008-07-15T18:11:59.000Z","updated":"2013-05-01T21:01:49.000Z","uploader":"burloandbardsey","category":"News","title":"bbc news start up theme","description":"bbc","thumbnail":{"sqDefault":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/4TSJhIZmL0A/default.jpg","hqDefault":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/4TSJhIZmL0A/hqdefault.jpg"},"player":{"default":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4TSJhIZmL0A&feature=youtube_gdata_player","mobile":"http://m.youtube.com/details?v=4TSJhIZmL0A"},"content":{"5":"http://www.youtube.com/v/4TSJhIZmL0A?version=3&f=videos&app=youtube_gdata","1":"rtsp://v5.cache7.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQlAL2aGhIk04RMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp","6":"rtsp://v5.cache7.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQlAL2aGhIk04RMYESARFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp"},"duration":15,"aspectRatio":"widescreen","rating":4.6683936,"likeCount":"354","ratingCount":386,"viewCount":341066,"favoriteCount":0,"commentCount":155,"accessControl":{"comment":"allowed","commentVote":"allowed","videoRespond":"allowed","rate":"allowed","embed":"allowed","list":"allowed","autoPlay":"allowed","syndicate":"allowed"}}}';
```

Should work, you need to surround the string with either '' or "". In any case it would be a good idea to escape ", and ' in the string.

Comment: I already check it the way of code. But my json value has any `' '` or `" "` means it will be ended.

Comment: Which is why i said you should escape those chars ;-)

Comment: How do i escape without assign this json value in a local variable? is it possible.

Comment: Well it depends on how you get the data, but you could use either str_replace or addslashes. see php.net for reference on how to use them

Comment: @YogeshSuthar : Yes. but no `quotes` in this example.

Comment: I knew that `add slashes` and `str_replace`, before I use this method of technique, how to i pass the `json data` or store it in a `local variable`.